# dual filtering in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I am working on chain of filtering and having trouble coming up with solution. first I am doing a filtering using search.input model and that is simple and works. I made a dropdown menu to additionally filter the result. for example. I put 'US' and it will show all users with US in the address property. then I select professional level dropdown to filter it further e.g only people with advanced skilllevel. Can someone advise on this?

Data to filter is something like this.

```
address: "Los Angeles, US"
avatar: "url"
bestAt: "NodeJS"
firstName: "Dan"
interest: "ExpressJS"
lastName: "Green"
skillLevel: "advanced"
yearExperience: 1
zipCode: "11870"


<div class="dropdown dropdownunit">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Professional Level
   <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Advanced</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Intermediate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Novice</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="user in search.users | filter:search.input">
  <div class="userinfo">
    <div class="userphotobox">
      <img class="userphoto" src="{{ user.avatar }}">
    </div>
    <p class="userinfobox">Name: {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</p>
    <p class="userinfobox">Location: {{user.address}}</p>
    <p class="userinfobox">Zip: {{user.zipCode}}</p>
    <p class="userinfobox">Skill Level: {{user.skillLevel}}</p>
    <p class="userinfobox">Experience: {{user.yearExperience}} years</p>
    <p class="userinfobox">bestAt: {{user.bestAt}}</p>
    <p class="userinfobox">Interest: {{user.interest}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aassumed that search.input be like:
`<input ng-model="search.input">`

Professional level should be turned to drop-down list with select tag.
IE:

```
<label>Professional Level</label>
<select ng-model="search.level">
  <option value="">Professional Level </option>
  <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
  <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
  <option value="Novice">Novice</option>
</select>
```

`ngRepeat` directive be like: `ng-repeat="user in search.users | filter:search"`

http://plnkr.co/edit/h8YjA4QTAMiLJqYoesmp?p=preview